# How to transfer money from one stripe account to multiple connected standalone stripe accounts

Tags: stripe-payments

I am working with a marketplace website. Initially, I will be charging a customer for buying a product and the money will be credited to my stripe account. After that, I want to transfer some money from my stripe account to two different standalone connected stripe accounts in. How can I achieve this using stripe?

Answer (score 1):

The exact feature you are looking for is [Transfer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers). Before April 6, 2017, transfers also represented movement of funds from a Stripe account to a card or bank account. This behaviour has since been split out into a Payout object, with corresponding payout endpoints.
[This link](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers#transfer-options) has detailed guide of how to create **Transfers**.

I know this was asked long ago but I couldn't find any satisfactory or to the point answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "Separate Charges & Transfers" flow described here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers.

I also recommend that you write to Stripe's support at https://support.stripe.com/email to explain your business model and desired payment flows to make sure that it's something that Stripe can support.

Comment: I've done the same thing. But I am getting an error like `stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_ACE28pBDJ2Clca: Cannot create transfers; please contact support@stripe.com with details, so we can help.
`

Comment: Please fetch your `account` and check value of `verification.fields_needed`. Perhaps you have reached your quota of maximum transfers before verification of account. You might need to upload verification document to reenable transfers on your account.

Comment: it's probably failing because this feature is in beta and limited to specific regions...